# How to remove app bar in fragment without .NoActionBar in themes

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

I need to remove this `home_fragment` action bar, but I can't write `NoActionBar` in `themes.xml` because bottom navigation won't work that way. Anyone has any solution?

Also, take a look at the photo, it will help understand the problem.
This is the code given in bottom navigation activity `XML`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Add player fragment"
        app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_bottom_navigation_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topAppBar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these two lines to your themes.xml files

```
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Themes.xml file looks like this
[image]